# Gradient + Rounded Corner CSS Issue in IE9

Tags: html, css

In my current project, I've used CSS3 gradient in my CSS file. To support IE browser, I've used filter property as well. Following is my code:

```
.card.active .content.back {
  background: #333; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333 0%, #0e0e0e 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#333), color-stop(100%,#0e0e0e)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* IE10+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#333333', endColorstr='#0e0e0e',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #333 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* W3C */

}
```

But when I use the `filter` property in the above code, the `border-radius` property is not working. If anyone know a fix for this, please share it with me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **PIE.htc** for your desired results.

PIE stands for Progressive Internet Explorer. It is an IE attached behavior which, when applied to an element, allows IE to recognize and display a number of CSS3 properties.

PIE currently adds full or partial support to IE 6 through 8 for the following CSS3 features:

```
border-radius
box-shadow
border-image
multiple background images
linear-gradient as background image
```

In addition, PIE adds support for border-image and linear-gradient to IE 9, which already supports the other features natively.

**http://css3pie.com/**

or see the demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/ZxzSs/1/

for support PIE.htc you have to keep the PIE.htc file on your root folder than will work for your website....

Comment: Hi @Shailender: I already using CSS3Pie, but the problem is, when I use it with the `filter` property, the div area is not getting the border-radius property in IE9. Though thanks for your answer, do you know a way to apply border-radius for a container which use filter to get the gradient background

Thanks

Comment: @Mujahid if you are using CSS3PIE so you don't need to use any kind of filter because through PIE.htc you can achive all the results like:- border-radius,box-shadow & gradient in IE and its support till IE6 to IE9.....and why are you using filter property if u have other solution ?

Comment: @Shailendar: Actually the filter property used by previous developer and I don't have any idea why he did it like that. I had an issue when I mouse hover the web page, the container which uses `filter` property background getting changed to white. So I removed the `filter` property and used PIE.htc and problem solved. But in my application, the div area is -8 degree transformed. When I use PIE.htc, the transformation degree getting change

Comment: just make a seperate style sheet for ie and than apply this thing to in that stylesheet....

Comment: Thanks I'm in, hope I can get the answer thr

Comment: Wasted an hour on PIE and it did nothing for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to apply the gradient to a child of the element with the rounded corners. I don't have access to IE9 on my home machine but this should work:

```
.element {
    background: linear-gradient(top, #333 0%,#0e0e0e 100%); /* W3C */
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.element .ie-helper {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#333333', endColorstr='#0e0e0e',GradientType=0 );
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="element">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><div class="ie-helper"><![endif]-->
    <p>Your content with gradient and rounded corners...</p>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]></div><![endif]-->
</div>
```

If the page is viewed in IE10+ or other browsers, both the gradient and rounded corners will apply to same element (assuming you bring back the vendor-specific prefixes from your code sample). The inner `div.ie-helper` will only render on IE9 and below because of the [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) used.

This isn't ideal but would get the job done, but since you're after such a wide range of browsers to be fully supported this is a reasonable workaround